# SImple way to redirect 403 and 404 errors to the main page htaccess

Tags: .htaccess

As the title says is there any easy way to redirect every forbidden error and page not found to my main page index.php?

Here is my htaccess don't think it will be of any use but here it is:

```
ErrorDocument 404 /leaguenotes/administration/cms/new_patch
ErrorDocument 403 /leaguenotes/administration/cms/new_patch

Options ALL -Indexes

RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^([0-9/.]+)$ index.php?Patch_No=$1 [NC,L]

RewriteRule ^([0-9/.]+)&([0-9a-zA-Z_-]+)$ index.php?Patch_No=$1&tab=$2 [NC,L]

RewriteRule ^patches php/patches.php [NC,L]

RewriteRule ^([0-9a-zA-Z_-]+)$ index.php?Champion=$1 [NC,L]
```

Answer (score 6):

You can add these 2 lines on top of your .htaccess:

```
ErrorDocument 404 /
ErrorDocument 403 /
```

This will redirect every `403` and `404` errors to your home page.

Comment: Could I redirect it to certain index? e.g. http://localhost/leaguenotes/administration/cms/new_patch
I would like redirect this to localhost/leaguenotes which is the homepage

Comment: Yes sure you can use any URL in the target. So `ErrorDocument 404 /leaguenotes/administration/cms/new_patch` will also work

Comment: that's what ive tried
ErrorDocument 404 /leaguenotes/administration/cms/new_patch
ErrorDocument 403 /leaguenotes/administration/cms/new_patch
and i got:
Additionally, a 301 Moved Permanently error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.
I want to redirect every error from every possible subpage to main index.php

Comment: That is due to your other rules. Edit the question with your full .htaccess for investigation

Comment: That was my full .htaccess ive just added those 2 lines i just mentioned (edited post)

Comment: What happens when you enter `http://domain.com/leaguenotes/administration/cms/new_patch` in browser?

Comment: Comment out both `ErrorDocument` lines and then enter `http://domain.com/leaguenotes/administration/cms/new_patch` in browser?

Comment: Well that means your URL is forbidden anyway. That has nothing to do with the `ErrorDocument` I suggested. Better to use `ErrorDocument 403 /`

Answer (score 3):

You can try this on top of your .htaccess file

```html
ErrorDocument 403 "<meta http-equiv='refresh' content='0; url=your_redirect_page.html'/>"
```